# Map a complex object of errors to its associated input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

Suppose I have the following fields

```
<input name="a" />
<input name="b[0]" />
<input name="b[1]" />
<input name="c[d]" />
<input name="c[e][f]" />
```

and the following object that hold errors for each input

```
var errors = {
    a: 'error a ',     // a's error
    b: [
        'error b0',    // b[0]'s error
        'error b1'     // b[1]'s error
    ],
    c: {
        d: 'error cd ', // c[d]'s error
        e: {
            f: 'error cef'  // c[e][f]'s error
        }
    }
}
```

What would be an efficient way to map each error to its related input?

```
<input name="a" />
<div class="error">error a</div>
<input name="b[0]" />
<div class="error">error b0</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

The only way I can think of doing this is by looping over the input `name` attributes and using `eval` to evaluate each one -- which probably isn't good. Something like:

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    var name = this.name.replace(/^([a-z0-9_\-]+)(.*)$/i, 'errors[$1]$2');
    var error = eval(name);

    $(this).after('<div class="error">' + error + '</div>');
});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to get each error by name of current input element and then use `after` to add it after current input element.

```js
var errors = {"a":"error a ","b":["error b0","error b1"],"c":{"d":"error cd ","e":{"f":"error cef"}}}

function f(name, obj) {
  return name
    .split(/[[\]]{1,2}/)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .reduce((r, e, i, arr) => {
      return r[e] || (r[e] = arr[i + 1] ? {} : '')
    }, obj)
}

$("input").each(function() {
  let error = f($(this).attr('name'), errors)
  if(error.length) $(this).after(`<div class="error">${error}</div>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="a" />
<input name="b[0]" />
<input name="b[1]" />
<input name="c[d]" />
<input name="c[e][f]" />
```

Comment: Wow nice. Would you mind explaining what `r[e] || (r[e] = arr[i + 1] ? {} : '')` does?

Comment: It's looking for nested value inside object or accumulator which will be your errors object by iterating through names array. And this `r[e] || (r[e] = arr[i + 1] ? {} : '')` just means if its last element and there is no match return empty string otherwise return empty object so you dont get error if some key is not found